# Auth0/Okta Authenticate Third Party Provider with dynamic login URLs

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, salesforce, auth0, okta

> TLDR: Is there a way to dynamically set the login URL during app
> runtime for either Auth0, Okta, or some other authentication service?

I am developing a capacitor application that uses Salesforce data. My app users will need to authenticate to Salesforce to retrieve permission (access token, refresh token, etc) for the app to grab their Salesforce data. The catch is the user can customize their login url based on the Salesforce sandbox they wish to hook my app up too during app run time. For instance they can use the choose to access a

- prod sandbox via `https://login.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`
- development sandbox via `https://test.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`
- specific sandbox via `https://${customSandboxDomain}.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Due to the user being able to determine which sandbox/domain they would like to authenticate to the app needs to be able to dynamically declare the authentication login url. Is there a way to dynamically set the login URL during app runtime for either Auth0, Okta, or some other authentication service?